# Python cx_Oracle call function that returns %ROWTYPE

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to read data from a legacy Oracle function using Python and cx_Oracle. The function has a declaration like this:

In the ITEM_PACKAGE:

```
FUNCTION get_item (p_itemName IN item.item_name%TYPE)
  RETURN item%ROWTYPE;
```

The function returns a row from an ITEM table like this:

```
TABLE ITEM_SCHEMA.ITEM {
  ITEM_ID NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL,
  CREATON_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(4000),
  …
}
```

I am trying to use cx_Oracle to call the function as follows:

```
return_type = connection.gettype('ITEM_SCHEMA.ITEM%ROWTYPE')
params = ['my_item_name']
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.callfunc('ASCHEMA.ITEM_PACKAGE.get_item', return_type, params)
```

which resulted in:

```
Exception: Varaible_TypeByPythonType(): unhandled_data_type
```

I also tried calling cursor.var() for the ROWTYPE:

```
return_type = cursor.var(connection.gettype('ITEM_SCHEMA.ITEM%ROWTYPE'))
```

which resulted in:

```
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Varaible_TypeByPythonType(): unhandled_data_type
```

Does anyone have an example of how to use cx_Oracle to call a function that returns a %ROWTYPE?

I am new to cx_Oracle, and have been successful in making calls to stored procedures that return simple types like cx_Oracle.STRING, and even cx_Oracle.CURSOR, but I don't know how to handle %ROWTYPE.

---

Edit: saw post: [cx_Oracle: Using PL/SQL RECORD types as arguments to stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360966/cx-oracle-using-pl-sql-record-types-as-arguments-to-stored-procedures?rq=1)

Tried call newobject() on the "cx_type", no joy.

---

Edit: In the original post I was calling cursor.callproc() instead of cursor.callfunc()

---

Edit: I saw [How to get custom object from callfunc in cx_Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105683/how-to-get-custom-object-from-callfunc-in-cx-oracle)

It said "The ability to bind Oracle objects is only available in the unreleased (development) version of cx_Oracle". I am now using the latest cx_oracle version 7.2.2. Version 7.2.2 should support this?

Comment: Have you tried using callfunc instead of callproc? It looks like you are calling a function so it returns something.

Comment: OMG,  face-palm!  I had been working with stored procedures for so long that I didn't notice that in this case I was calling a function! Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 2):

This [sample](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/PLSQLRecord.py) should help you figure out how to do it. table%rowtype is a PL/SQL record and so must be processed as an object. If this doesn't help, please provide the full code you are using to call the stored procedure and the definition of the stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you Anthony for your reply, but I think I am calling the cursor.callfunc() correctly, but it keeps throwing and Exception Variable_TypeByPythonType(): unhandled data type. Is there something else I need to do for ROWTYPE?

Comment: What version of cx_Oracle are you using? Version 7.1.2 introduced the ability to call the function as you have in your code above. Prior to that you would have had to create a variable instead, or used an anonymous PL/SQL block and performed the binding directly yourself.

Comment: I have cx_oracle version 6.0.2, I will try to update it, thank you.

Comment: I re-built the docker image with cx_oracle 7.2.2, python 3.6 and CentOS 7. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. Are there any examples of using cx_oracle to call functions with rowtype objects?

Comment: The sample I provided should help, but there is no direct sample as you requested. Please post an issue on cx_Oracle requesting this (and link back to here) and I will look at adding such a sample when I get back from my conference in a couple of weeks.